# How to move object grid base continuously?

Tags: unity, grid

I want to move object continously when I press button just once  grid to grid. When I press button to make object move to another  direction, it should wait until object is right on the grid and starts to move another direction. Those are my codes. It moves continously when I press once but doesn't move grid to grid

```
void GridMove()
{
    

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        forward = true;
        back = false;
        left = false;
        right = false;

    }


    
    if (forward)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveCharacter(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        back = true;
        forward = false;
        left = false;
        right = false;


    }


    if (back)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveCharacter(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        left = true;
        back = false;
        forward = false;
        right = false;
        

    }


    if (left)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveCharacter(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime));
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        right = true;
        back = false;
        forward = false;
        left = false;


    }


    if (right)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveCharacter(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime));
    }












}


private IEnumerator MoveCharacter(Vector3 direction)
{
    

    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    originPos = transform.position;
    targetPos = originPos + direction;


    while (elapsedTime < timeToMove)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPos, targetPos, (elapsedTime / timeToMove));
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }


    transform.position = targetPos;



    
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the point of the 4 bools? can't you remove them and start the coroutine right in the button check condition? else it would as well continue to move for eternity in that direction since you never set them all to false;

Comment: Actually you are right. I fixed. But any suggestion about question ?